# Вычислить сумму 1-1/2+1/3-...(-1)^n+1*1/n в VBA

Tags: vba

Вычислить сумму 1-1/2+1/3-...(-1)^n+1*1/n условный оператор и операцию возведение в степень не использовать.

Comment: l:=1;
sum:=0;
for i:=1 to n do
begin
 sum:=sum+(l*(1/i));
 l:=-l;
end;

Comment: если это ответ на ваш вопрос, добавьте ответом.

Comment: `1*1/n` - какая-то бессмысленная запись, может так надо было `(-1)^n*1/n`?

Comment: или все-таки так `( (-1)^n + 1 ) * 1/n`?

Comment: @slippyk *какая-то бессмысленная запись* Там не единица, а переменная по фамилии l (в верхнем регистре L которая).

Comment: @Akina в описании вопроса единица

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Sign As Integer
Dim Sum As Double

Sign = -1
Sum = 0

For N = 1 To 10
    Sign = Sign * (-1)
    Sum = Sum + Sign * (1 / N)
Next N
```

Comment: Зачем нужно переменная Sign? можно тупо `(-1)^(N MOD 2)`.

Comment: @Akina `операцию возведение в степень не использовать`

Comment: @Akina не стоит по соображениям производительности, даже если бы не было явного запрета в задании. Инверсия знака у целого числа быстрее и точнее возведения его в степень. Как минимум не выполняется преобразование во float и обратно. Да и сама экспонента как правило считается через сумму рядов, а это цепочка умножений и сложений float-ов.

Comment: @slippyk Ну что-нить вроде `2*(N MOD 2)-1`... какая в пень разница-то?

Answer (score 0):

Считаем с шагом

```
Sub SumSeries()
Dim Sum As Double, n As Long

For n = 2 To 10 Step 2
    Sum = Sum + (1 / (n - 1)) - (1 / n)
Next n

Debug.Print Sum
End Sub
```